# Integration test good practice

Tags: c#, integration-testing

I am using unit test for some time. But now I need to write integration test. I should save something to DB, and than check if saved data is ok.
I can't find simple clean example of integration test.
My idea is to do like this:

```
[Test]
public void IntegrationTestExample()
{
    // Arrange without mocking
    var objec1 = new objec1();
    var objec2 = new objec2();

    var startTestClass = new startTestClass(objec1, objec2);
    var saveData = "test data";

    //Act
    startTestClass.SaveToDB(saveData);

    // Assert
    var valueFromDB = SelectSavedData();
    Assert.AreEqual(saveData, valueFromDB);
}

//Get data from DB for assert
private string SelectSavedData() 
{
    var sqlQuery = "Select TOP 1 data from table1";                
    var data = RepositoryForTest.selectSavedData(sqlQuery);
    return data;
}
```

But I am not sure if this is good approach?
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Shouldn't you split this into 2 tests? One to save the data, and one to get the data. You want to test the save method works. You also want to test the retrieve method works?

Comment: @Jamie Rees No, retrieve method is here just to get data for assert. To check if value is saved to DB. Retrieve method is just for integration test purpose.

Comment: I don't think this is really a integration test. It looks like a simple test for your datalayer. Normally a integration test, tests multiple components.

Comment: I don't like this type of test to be quite honest. Shouldn't your `SaveToDB` return something? e.g. a bool

Comment: Let's say I have multiple components in SaveToDB method. I just did not want to write complicate example. And it is integration test because it using DB.

Comment: What testing frmework are you using?

Comment: @Jamie Rees  No, it should not return anything. SaveToDB in my case insert many rows in DB. But in test purpose I will insert just one row.

Comment: @3dd Microsoft Unit Test Framework

Comment: Ok then see my answer as it's based on MS testing framework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should test one piece of integration at a time, and leave the DB in such a state that it can run multiple tests and they should not affect each other.  The MS test framework allows you to define methods that will setup and cleanup the tests at certain times during the test run, as shown in the following code

```
[TestClass]
public class ReturnServiceTest {
    [ClassInitialize()]
    public static void ClassInit(TestContext context) {
        //INIT TEST DATA FOR THE CLASS
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void TestCleanup() {
        //CLEANUP DATA AFTER EACH TEST
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void IntegrationTestExample() {
        // Arrange without mocking
        var objec1 = new objec1();
        var objec2 = new objec2();

        var startTestClass = new startTestClass(objec1, objec2);
        var saveData = "test data";

        //Act
        startTestClass.SaveToDB(saveData);

        // Assert
        var valueFromDB = SelectSavedData();
        Assert.AreEqual(saveData, valueFromDB);
    }

    //Get data from DB for assert
    private string SelectSavedData() {
        var sqlQuery = "Select TOP 1 data from table1";
        var data = RepositoryForTest.selectSavedData(sqlQuery);
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it make sense to put the "Infrastructure" code in a common library? By infrastructure, I mean the creation of dependencies of our SUT.

Comment: @VinShahrdar what is SUT?

Comment: System Under Test. In this case, the line of code in your "Act".

Comment: The variable names shouldn't contain typos.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using a real database you should *clean it up after each test* attempt.

How you access the data is also not very clear, what proves, that `RepositoryForTest` does not contain any errors? Try to do the simp*lest thing that is possible for your assertion*.

My Tests against databases look like:

```
    public void Test()
    {
        try
        {
            // Fixture setup
            // Create and insert data into Database (with plain ADO code)

            // Exercise system


            // Verify outcome
            // use your data layer here
        }
        finally
        {
            // Teardown - other methods to clean the tables afterwards
            DatabaseHelper.ClearLookups();
            DatabaseHelper.ClearBeds();
            ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: RepositoryForTest just select data from DB. Select same data that is inserted with SaveToDB method. This is class used just in test.